# Why is mmap done during printfs calls?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system, elf, libc

Why does printf() do an *sys_mmap()* and then copy the contents of string in chunks (of 1024) to new address space for *sys_write()* ?

**Strace of simple static "hello" program is shown below.**

```
> gcc -o hello -static hello.c
> strace ./hello


execve("./hello", ["./hello"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="Kumar", ...})   = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1ce8000
brk(0x1ce91c0)                          = 0x1ce91c0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x1ce8880)      = 0
readlink("/proc/self/exe", "/home/admin/hello", 4096) = 18
brk(0x1d0a1c0)                          = 0x1d0a1c0
brk(0x1d0b000)                          = 0x1d0b000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 28), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feda2130000
write(1, "Hello", 5Hello)                    = 5
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

**Objdump of rodata**

```
> objdump -s --start-address=0x4935a0 ./hello | head -5

./hello:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .rodata:
 4935a0 01000200 48656c6c 6f006c69 62632d73  ....Hello.libc-s
```

If we hook the address of *sys_write()* system call at kernel level, we see the address passed to it is of *mmap*-ed address region. Is it not just a waste of new address space, given that the string already exits in .rodata section in first loadable segment of binary. Has it got something to do with NO write permissions etc? Then why not make compiler put the string in .data section (which is writable as well) at first place?

**UPDATE:**

Mmap-ed address is indeed for *sys_write()* which can be verified in an easier way when we make the string bigger (say ~1500 chars). GDB will confirm the data address being printed [Note the second breakpoint]

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hello World hhhhhhhhhhalhfafeuirafheuhrgiegieguehguergjkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww     pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiwqiuwqiuwiquwiqhchasnvjnavjanvjdanvjdanvjdanjfanvjaddijuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuquweuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuunnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Breakpoint 1, _IO_new_file_write (f=0x6b8300 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, data=0x7ffff7ffc000, n=706) at fileops.c:1257
1257    {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using a debugger?

```
$ gdb /tmp/hello
...
(gdb) b __mmap
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4152e0    
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/hello 

Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004152e0 in mmap64 ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004152e0 in mmap64 ()
#1  0x000000000045d73c in _IO_file_doallocate ()
#2  0x0000000000401fec in _IO_doallocbuf ()
#3  0x000000000042ca10 in _IO_new_file_overflow ()
#4  0x000000000042be9d in _IO_new_file_xsputn ()
#5  0x000000000040111d in puts ()
#6  0x00000000004004de in main () at hello.c:4
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hello, w
[Inferior 1 (process 4294) exited with code 011]
```

So it allocates memory for buffered input-output, which `FILE*` uses. Note that using printf with only constant string will cause puts call because GCC is smart enough.  And `puts(string)` is actually an `fputs(string, stdout)` where stdout is `FILE*`.

Using raw write, however doesn't incur such behaviour:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    write(1, "Hello, w\n", sizeof("Hello, w\n"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But I am somewhat not fully getting the explanation. You mean to say the mmap-ed address is of stdout (FILE*)?

Comment: No, the `mmap`  is used from `malloc`  called from `fopen` or `printf` or `puts`; ` malloc`  is used to allocate the `stdout`'s data buffer.

Comment: [See my Update] The newly mmaped region is indeed for storing data. Notice what happens when string grows bigger. The data parameter is pointing to MMAP address. So my question remains valid

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - Little more explanation about data buffer please. U mean to say a 'fixed' buffer space is created for printing. Where my actual data is copied to  in chunks?

Comment: @SandhyaKumar a FILE* contains a buffer to store data when performing read/write operation on it. (printf implicitly uses the global FILE* named stdout). You can manipulate a FILE* to be line buffered, unbuffered or fully buffered. Data is stored in that buffer, and not written to the underlying device (e.g. your terminal/console) until you write a newline if the FILE* is line buffered, or the buffer is full, or you explicitly call fflush();

Comment: @nos Awesome point -- I realized every newline invoking separate write() syscalls.  Is there any special content that get appended along with my actual data to constitute the buffer ? In that case, agreed to take extra space for buffer. If not, my question is why is there a requirement to do the FILE* buffer in first place? Cannot my rodata content be directly fetched/parsed (in a way compatible to underlying devices)?

Comment: @SandhyaKumar There is a buffer because that's the point of *buffered I/O* - the data written is *buffered* until some condition is true. With terminal devices, stdio usually (but not necessarily) is in line buffered mode, which means everything you write to console is buffered until either the buffer is full or you write a newline character. This buffer obviously needs to be allocated, and that's what `mmap(2)` is doing.